# How to queue files before upload in client side with Meteor/Javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to upload files in bulk (like 80-100 files) in client side managed by queues like Mega.

I'm working with Meteor.js but I can work with anything in javascript.

[image]

Comment: You can just put the files in an array and then when the length of that array is 80 - 100 then you upload all of them at once

Comment: have a look at [Power Queue](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-power-queue)